# Offline data caching mechanism in hybrid application

Tags: node.js, angular, mobile, web, ionic-framework

I am developing application using Angular2 and ionic in back end i am using node. In my application i have some html forms these forms contain common input fields and image upload.

If the user don't have net connection user can able to complete the form without any problem. Once he get internet connection at that time it will upload to server.

How can we implement this feature in web and mobile separately ?

Whats the best solution for this scenario. Please suggest i don't have any clear picture about this one.

Answer (score 0):

To understand what offline scenarios are good candidates for a mobile web app, it helps to first understand the key technologies that make it possible.

Mobile web apps can be built with three core capabilities, and all of these are part of the new HTML5 standards:

1. Browser application caching of pages
2. Local storage
3. Local database

**Browser application caching** allows a manifest to be created listing pages that should be cached and made available offline. Normally, when you visit a URL, a server request is made to return the page. Setting up an application cache manifest tells the browser how it can use pages already downloaded rather than just immediately displaying an error when there is no longer a network connection.

**Local Storage** is a standard that retains local web app data (even when the browser is shut down) using a key/value system that works similarly to browser cookies. However, it is different from browser cookies in two important ways. First, cookies are resent to the server with every HTTP request, and it would waste a lot of bandwidth to resend all offline data when the server doesn’t need it. Secondly, cookies tend to max out at around 4k of data, while local storage usually gives an application as much as 5 MB of data to work with per domain. 5 MB may not sound like much, but when used carefully, it can go a very long way in terms of offline local storage.

**Local Database** removes the 5MB limit of local storage and allows data to be indexed so that multiple properties can be queried quickly. This is only an HTML5 proposed standard at present; only Internet Explorer and Firefox have implemented it so far. Safari and Chrome use an older, deprecated system called Web SQL. This means if you need this level of functionality, there is a significant amount of extra work and complexity to support both standards across all major browsers. Hopefully, that won’t always be the case and major browsers will conform to the finalized HTML5 specifications.

Comment: I have one doubt. is it possible to use google drive offline caching for data store and image upload.

Answer (score 0):

When user is offline store form data in localStorage, and when it comes online get data form localStorage upload it to server and remove data from localStorage.

```
localStorage.setItem('form_data', formData) //Store data in localStorage

localStorage.getItem('form_data') //Get form localStorage

localStorage.removeItem('form_data') //Remove from localStrage
```

Add eventlistner on window

```
if (typeof navigator.onLine !== 'undefined') { 
    window.addEventListener('offline', function (ev) { 
        userOffline();
    }); 
    window.addEventListener('online', function (ev) { 
        userOnline();
    }); 
}


function userOnline() {} // when user online
function userOffline() {} // when user offline
```